# Silverligth, how to give an observablecollection of UserControl as itemsource to a listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a list of observable collection of UserControl in my MVVM silverlight project. I want to give them as source to a listbox datasource. How can I achieve this.

```
 <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource Menu}" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" DisplayMemberPath="Libelle" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus.UnderControl}" />                                </ListBox>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have a UserControl called `myUserControl1`, and `myUserControl1.Menus` is an `ObservableCollection`.

and you wish to bind myListBox1.ItemsSource to myUserControl1.Menus. Then you should use the ElementName key word in your binding. For example:

```
<my:CustomControl x:Name="myUserControl1" />
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox1" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Menus,ElementName=myUserControl1}" />
```